# How to query for ids in Criteria for a List of GeneticAdditionalInfo

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a list of Genetic classes that store information on genes. and I want select the list of GeneAdditionalInfo which is stored in a separate database based on the GeneticId stored in a different MongoDb database. The GeneticId class is the key used from the GeneticInfo object to retrieve the GeneticAdditionalInfo data. In my code, I first obtain the list of GeneticId's from the GeneticInfo list of objects and the create a query based on the list of GeneticId's to build a Query which should return the list of GeneticAdditionalInfo list using the MongoTemplate find(Query, Class<?>) method.
Here are the classes:

```java
                   import lombok.Data;
                   import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

                   @Data
                   public class GeneticId {
                     @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
                     private String genderCode;
                     @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
                     private Long geneGroupId;

                     public GeneticId(String genderCode, Long geneGroupId) {
                      this.genderCode = genderCode;
                      this.geneGroupId = geneGroupId;
                     }
                    }


                   import lombok.Data;
                   import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
                   import org.springframework.data.annotation.PersistenceCreator;
                   import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

                   @Data
                   @Document
                   public class GeneticInfo {
                     @Id
                     private GeneticId geneticId;
                     private String dnaString;
                     private String qualityFactor;
                     private String labName;

                     @PersistenceCreator
                     public GeneticInfo(GeneticId geneticId, String dnaString, String 
                        qualityFactor, String labName) {
                        
                        this.geneticId = geneticId;
                        this.dnaString = dnaString;
                        this.qualityFactor = qualityFactor;
                        this.labName = labName;
                      }
                    }

                    import lombok.Data;

                    @Data
                    public class GeneAdditionalnfo {
                      private String classification;
                      private String type;
                    }
```

Here is the class using the GeneticId to attempt to find the GeneAdditionalnfo data

```java
                   import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
                   import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
                   import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
                   import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
                   import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

                   import java.util.*;
                   import java.util.stream.Collectors;

                   @Service
                   @RequiredArgsConstructor
                   public class GeneticInfoQueryService {
                     private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

                     public List<GeneAdditionalnfo> 
                        findAdditionCharacteristics(List<GeneticInfo> geneticInfoList){
       
                     List<GeneticId> geneticIds = geneticInfoList.stream().map(geneInfo -> 
                     geneInfo.getGeneticId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
                  
                      Query query = new Query();
                      Criteria criteria = new Criteria("id").in(geneticIds);
                      query.addCriteria(criteria);
                   
                      List<GeneAdditionalnfo> additionalnfoList = 
                      mongoTemplate.find(query,  GeneAdditionalnfo.class);
                    
                     return additionalnfoList;
                 }

               }
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work Can someone point me what I am not right?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing from id to geneticId as below:

```
                  Criteria criteria = new Criteria("geneticId").in(geneticIds);
```